# Код шаблона в C++

Tags: c++

Существует ли способ построить в классе группу "одинаковых" методов, но использующих каждый одно уникальное свойство/параметр, при помощи шаблона (template) или других техник, чтобы не писать определения для каждого "типового" метода?

Поясню примером - ниже код (используемый в блоке шаблона проектирования "наблюдатель"), который хотелось-бы упростить/сократить при помощи использования "template" (или других методов) чтобы уменьшить вероятность возможных ошибок при увеличении количества и функционала наблюдателей:

```
class MyService {
  viod add_f0_observer(MyType& ref);
  viod add_f1_observer(MyType& ref);
  viod add_f2_observer(MyType& ref);

  void event_caller();

  MyType* f0_observer;
  MyType* f1_observer;
  MyType* f2_observer;
}

viod MyService::add_f0_observer(MyType& ref) {
    f0_observer = &ref;
    // ...
}

viod MyService::add_f1_observer(MyType& ref) {
    f1_observer = &ref;
    // ...
}

viod MyService::add_f2_observer(MyType& ref) {
    f2_observer = &ref;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Исходя из ответа @Ant, то можно предположить, что в таком случае вам помогут только макросы. В c++ кодо-генерацию ещё не завезли.

Comment: @MrBin да, учитывая что макросы признаны злом, чуда не случится.

Comment: @bigov А Вам обязательно делать три отдельных поля? Может проще сделать массив указателей на наблюдателей? Или список? Тогда Вам вообще  не понадобится изобретать способы обратиться к разным полям.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем конкретном примере общий код и так прост до предела, поэтому еще больше "упростить" его не получится. Но если предположить, что в реальном коде общий код будет существенно более объемным, отличаясь в трех своих вариантом только использованием поля `f0_observer`, `f1_observer` или `f2_observer`, то возможность упрощения есть.

Эту задачу можно решить без шаблонов, объявив "универсальную" функцию с обычным параметром типа указатель-на-член-класса

```
class MyService 
{
  void add_observer(MyType *MyService::*field, MyType& ref)
  { 
    // ...
    this->*field = &ref; 
    // ...
  }

  void add_f0_observer(MyType& ref)
    { add_observer(&MyService::f0_observer, ref); }
  void add_f1_observer(MyType& ref)
    { add_observer(&MyService::f1_observer, ref); }
  void add_f2_observer(MyType& ref)
    { add_observer(&MyService::f2_observer, ref); }

  MyType* f0_observer;
  MyType* f1_observer;
  MyType* f2_observer;
};
```

Понятно, что в данном примере и указатель-на-член-класса тут не обязателен: можно было бы в качестве первого параметра использовать обычную ссылку или указатель на `MyType`. Но я специально использовал именно указатель-на-член-класса, ибо он в таком случае будет являться константой времени компиляции.

Если учесть, что такой указатель является константой времени компиляции, можно превратить его из обычного параметра в шаблонный параметр

```
class MyService 
{
  template <MyType *MyService::*field> void add_observer(MyType& ref)
  { 
    // ...
    this->*field = &ref; 
    // ...
  }

  void add_f0_observer(MyType& ref)
    { add_observer<&MyService::f0_observer>(ref); }
  void add_f1_observer(MyType& ref)
    { add_observer<&MyService::f1_observer>(ref); }
  void add_f2_observer(MyType& ref)
    { add_observer<&MyService::f2_observer>(ref); }

  MyType* f0_observer;
  MyType* f1_observer;
  MyType* f2_observer;
};
```

Стоит ли это делать - вопрос отдельный.

Ту же самую идею можно реализовать не только через голые указатели, но и через более высокоуровневые средства языка: `std::bind` или лямбды.

Comment: Я понял, одинаковый функционал описывается в коде шаблона, а различия в определениях функций указываются через обращение к нему (шаблону). Это дает возможность сильно сократить код определения методов. Но все равно придется писать опреления для каждого метода по их числу. А есть способы обойти последнее?

Comment: @bigov: Не совсем понятно, о чем именно вы ведете речь. Вам же в любом случае надо тем или иным образом указывать, с каким именно полем вы хотите работать в каждом случае. То есть какие-то отличия все равно будут. Можно лишь постараться максимально вынести эти отличия "за скобки", что я и попытался сделать выше. Или ваш вопрос о том, как организовать *цикл* по этим полям?

Comment: у меня идея как-то реализовать уникальное вычисляемое имя поля для каждого метода при помощи шаблона. Хотя, это наверно просто запутает код и сделает его нечитабельным. Идея "фикс".

Answer (score 0):

Я может и не очень понел ваши намерения, поскольку логично в классе просто хранить контейнер и каждый раз в нем просто добавлять элемент. Но, насколько я понел что вы хотите сделать, напишу пример:

```
template<size_t Tab, class Seq = std::vector< MyType*>> 
class MyService {
    //хранит контейнер нулевых указателей
    Seq observers = Seq(Tab, nullptr);
    //...
public: 
    template<size_t k>
    void add_observer(MyType& ref) 
    {
        //каким нибудь образом не позволить
        // выход за пределы контейнера
        if constexpr (k >= Tab)
            observers[Tab - 1] = &ref;
        else
            observers[k] = &ref;
    }
    //...   
};
//и если вам нужен класс с тремя указательями
//то инстанцируйте этот класс один раз
template class MyService<3>; //пользуется вектором

//дальше можете использовать например так:
void add(MyService<3> &s, std::array<MyType, 3> arr)
{
    /*инстанцируем 3 функции_члена, каждая из которых
    будет работать с соответствующим указателем*/       
    s.add_observer<0>(arr[0]);
    s.add_observer<1>(arr[1]);
    s.add_observer<2>(arr[2]);  // или
    s.add_observer<5>(arr[2]);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант с вынесением общей функциональности в шаблонную функцию, а конкретных реализаций - в перегруженную. Например:

```
class MyService{
public:
    struct f0_observer{ static constexpr int id = 0;};
    struct f1_observer{ static constexpr int id = 1;};
    struct f2_observer{ static constexpr int id = 2;};

    template<class O> auto add_observer(O type)->decltype(process(type)){
        observers[type.id] = &ref;
        /// Вместо type.id можно реализовать шаблонный список типов, позволяющий извлечь id по типу
        process(type);
    }
private:
    void process(f0_observer){ /*...*/} 
    void process(f1_observer){ /*...*/} 
    void process(f2_observer){ /*...*/} 

    std::array<MyType*> observers
}

void foo(){
   MyService s;
   MyType t;
   s.add_observer(MyService::f1_observer{}, &t);
   /*...*/   
}
```

Для данного конкретного случая это явно не оправдано.